# Is it possible to listen for specific word in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, voice-recognition, microphone, voice

I'm building an android app with React native.

https://github.com/react-native-community/voice This package is working well to capture voice. But I want the device to listen always and trigger an event after saying a specific word (like "Hello myapp!").

I've tried
https://github.com/spokestack/react-native-spokestack

But it's not working.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Voice from 'react-native-voice';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
 
class VoiceTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStartHandler.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = this.onSpeechEndHandler.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResultsHandler.bind(this);
  }
  onStartButtonPress(e){
    Voice.start('en-US');
  }
  ...
}
```

Also Checkout this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-voice it will help you alot.

Comment: It won't capture voice all time. Please check my question again.